# Can I read the label on a button with monkeyrunner

Tags: android, monkeyrunner

In general I want to write a monkeyrunner program that turns on Wifi on my android phone if it's not on already. I have the following code:

```
from com.android.monkeyrunner import MonkeyRunner, MonkeyDevice
package='com.android.settings'                                          
activity='.Settings'                           
component_name=package + "/" + activity                        
device = MonkeyRunner.waitForConnection()                      
device.startActivity(component=component_name)
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER', "DOWN_AND_UP")
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_DOWN')
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER', "DOWN_AND_UP")
device.press('KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER', "DOWN_AND_UP")
```

This code navigates to the screen where the wifi networks are detected. As I scroll down I want to check to see if the current button is for my network and if it is, and is not turned on, turn it on.

One thought I had was to read the label on the button for comparison. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This post ([monkeyrunner: interacting with views](http://dtmilano.blogspot.com/2012/02/monkeyrunner-interacting-with-views.html)), while doesn't contain the exact answer to your question, should give you the hints to solve your problem using [AndroidViewClient](https://github.com/dtmilano/AndroidViewClient).

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways that you could accomplish this. Both involve saving images using monkeyrunner result = device.takeSnapshot().

First you could use MonkeyImage.sameAs() to compare the two images, but to do this you would need to get both two images without restarting monkeyrunner as there is no way to load a saved monkeyimaged.

The other way involves using something like http://sikuli.org/ to compare the two images.

Answer (score 0):

a workaround is-
you can make use of  >Add Network option in android,Give the network name you want to connect.It should automatically connect to the added network.